# User unable to open or save workbook with VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, windows

The user is able to work with workbooks containing the code that were produced previously.
Recently new workbooks with the code cannot be opened or saved.

There are a range of error messages depending on where the workbook is opened from.

Error messages include:

> Excel cannot open the file Test.xslm because the file format or extension is not valid...'

Not true, as I can open the same workbook and run the code.

> Your changes to Text.xlsm could not be saved due to a sharing violation...'

Followed by more errors to do with not finding a temporary document.

We tried safe locations, local folders and Dropbox folders.
We also tried with code signed and unsigned workbooks.

I also tried removing ActiveX references which might flag as a security issue, (e.g. VBIDE) and commenting out blocks of code.
Microsoft Defender reports no issues. There are no other antivirus programs running.

There are no problems with with the VBA modules removed. It definitely looks code related.

Comment: Is this file on a company server? They Might have strict macro rules. If so, you maybe able to change them in your trust settings, or you might have to contact your IT. If this is your personal computer... I'm stumped.

Comment: I've checked all the trust centre settings - they exactly match the ones on machines where the code works.

Comment: Is one of these spreadsheets on SharePoint? (eg: shared violation mentioned).
WebExcel on SharePoint does not work the same.

Comment: We've tried copying the workbooks to local folders - so no sharepoint or dropbox, but the issues are the same. The files are opened in the desktop version of Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be because of ASR.

If you check your "Windows Security" --> Virus & threat protection --> Protection history, you should find an event of "Risky action blocked" that shows your file has been "Blocked by: Attack surface reduction" Rule: Block Win32 API calls from Office macro".

I'm currently facing a very similar issue but I'm on the other side (I am the one that enabled ASR rules).
If that is the case for you as well, I wonder whether the problem depends on the identity that you use to save the file through your macro. Are you using the same security context of the user executing Excel?

Comment: Thanks for the lead. I'll get the users to check their protection history to see if there's anything relevant. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: You were spot on. Have confirmed with users that this is what's going on. Now on to the infrastructure people to get them to apply a fix.

Comment: Glad I helped. I wonder if you could pls share the solution from your infrastructure team, once and if they provide one.
Thank you very much and Happy new Year :-)

Comment: They're testing a solution at the moment - as soon as it's confirmed that it's sorted the problems for all users I'll let you know

Comment: The tech support guys tried different things before finally getting it to work. They say it's a global rule to allow or disallow macro execution. Macro warnings are now restored and users can take appropriate action to go ahead and execute code.

Comment: OK so then they basically disable the rule. Thank you for the feedback!